# Divider position in full screen mode

Tags: java, javafx

I tried `setDividerPositions` with various arguments, but whatever arguments I provide my two stack panes inside of a split pane are of equal width. This is my simple code:

```
 SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
 final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
 final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
 sp.getItems().addAll(sp1, sp2);
 sp.setDividerPositions(0.3); // tried (0.3, 0.7) and other variants but does not work     
 Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
 primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
 primaryStage.show();
```

So, I do not know how to make it work, so that the left pane will be 30% in width, and the right pane will occupy 70%. Thanks!

PS. It seems like there is a bug in JavaFX, since when I launch the program the top-most bar with close and resize buttons is invisible, but becomes visible only when I hit Escape. (But probably I'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacobian, the problem seems to be with setting the FullScreen option to true.
Remove that statement and try again.  Also, give your scene an initial height and width value.  You can do this by giving it some default values, or by getting the users screen size and using those settings.
You can keep the user from resizing the application by setting the min height and width of the primary stage, although the user will still be able to move the app around.

```
        SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
        final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
        final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
        sp.getItems().addAll( sp1 , sp2 );
        double height = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
        double width = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth();
        // Scene scene = new Scene( sp, width, height );
        Scene scene = new Scene( sp );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.setMaximized( true );
        primaryStage.setMinHeight( height );
        primaryStage.setMinWidth( width );
        primaryStage.show();
        sp.setDividerPositions( 0.3 );
```

Comment: But what if it is a strict requirement to have a fullscreen mode?

Comment: I've edited my answer for that requirement.  Get the screen size, set the minimum stage sizes, and then set to maximize.  This might not be the best way to go about it though.  This keeps the window from being resizable even though it can be moved around.

Does the window need to be in full screen mode always, or just for the startup?

Comment: Screen is not defined in my context. Can you, please, advise what should I import?

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I imported `javafx.stage.Screen;` and made copy-paste of your code. Still both panes are of equal width - 50%.

Comment: Try setting the divider position after you show the stage.

Comment: You are right. I checked it and setFullScreen now works.